# Are software installation questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange occasionally gets questions about how to install DS/AI-related software. These are not on topic at AI, so I'm wondering whether it'd be appropriate to migrate them to DS. Searching for ["install"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=install) or ["installation"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=installation) turns up some questions closed with the generic off-topic reason, but also many that are still open. Are installation questions actually on-topic here, and if so, are there any special requirements for them to be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have considered them off-topic here, as they're more about using software packages and so probably best on SO.